# Nodejs objects - how to add value and define new property at the same time?

Tags: node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

Lets say I have an object:

```
var o = {
  i1: {
    p1: '1/1',
    p2: '1/2'
  }
};
```

I can address its elements like this:

```
console.log('i1 p2:',o['i1']['p2']);
```

I can set new 'vertical' property:

```
o['i1']['p3']='1/3';
console.table(o);

┌─────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ (index) │  p1   │  p2   │  p3   │
├─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│   i1    │ '1/1' │ '1/2' │ '1/3' │
└─────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

However I can not add another index ('horizontal' property) the same way:

```
o['i2']['p3']='2/3';
```

results in error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'p3' of undefined`

because there is no 'i2' property defined yet.
Is there any syntax to solve this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an *object* to the `i2` property, where the object has a `p3` property.

```
o.i2 = { p3: '2/3' }
```